# Using resx resources in .NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to use a resource(.resx) file in an ASP.NET Core project. I had it working in rc1 using a namedResource, but can't seem to get it working in RTM. Here is what my project.json looks like:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "embed": {
    "include": [ "Resources/resource.resx" ]
  }
}
```

And I'm accessing it like this:

```
Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Field1");
```

It seems the resources are not getting  embedded as There is nothing there when I debug.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Found the answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360068/localization-in-separate-project-asp-net-core-mvc

Comment: Here is Mr.mrfleck work around this problem. So, if i move the .resx files to the root of the project instead of in a sub-folder, it works as expected. I have tried every way to embed from a sub-folder and it no longer works. For now I will use this workaround, but I suspect this is a bug in RC2. Currently it is a tooling issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localization in separate project Asp.net Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360068/localization-in-separate-project-asp-net-core-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

For string in resource use:
Remove embed.

```
var x = ResourceFoo.Field1;
```

For file in resource use:
Include embed for file (ex.: /Folder1/**/*)
 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Folder1.Folder2.file.ext");